# Getting data from web service with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I think it's a syntax error because I am not very familiar with Javascript/JSON. Currently, this code does nothing. This is for school project; my class is building an app that connects users by providing an interface to book activities based on freetime/class schedule. Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var url = "http://3920project.azurewebsites.net/api/activity/";
        //var email = "?email=" + getUrlVars();
        //var title = "?title=" + "girls";
        var title = "?title=" + getTitle();

        //alert(url + title);
        $.getJSON(url + title)
        // data: {title: $("#title").val()
        .done(function(res) {
            //alert("done");
            $.each(res, function(key, item) {
                var colID = $('<td>', {
                text: item.category
                });
                var colName = $('<td>', {
                    text: item.day + item.to + item.from
                });
                $('<tr>').append(colID, colName).appendTo($('#tblResult:last'));
            }); //end of each()
        }); //end of done()
    }); //end of click()
}); //end of ready()
function getTitle() {
    return document.getElementById('title').value;
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: arial;
    }

    th,
    td {
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    }

    td {
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }

    th {
        background: #666;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    td:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #666;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<title>Activity Search</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="app">
    Please enter activity:
    <br></br>
    <input type="text" id="title">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
    <br></br>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Activity TimeTable</h2>
    <table id="tblResult">
        <tr>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you check with chrome dev tool for js error?

Comment: Check your `res`. It's a string. Use `JSON.parse(res)` to create an object

Comment: My classmate has a similar task and she didn't use JSON.parse(res) and hers is working fine. I think my issue has to do with the .click function because it's one of the few things that is done differently from hers as hers doesn't require input from the user.

Comment: There is no input with the ID `title` in your document.

Comment: @Wainage When you use `.getJSON`, it automatically parses it. That's the difference between `.get` and `.getJSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have a syntax error. If you open up your developer console (F12), you'll see that `uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token )` in Chrome. So something is wrong before that point.

In this case, it's not that you have an extra `)`, but rather the browser doesn't understand how to read what follows `getJSON()`. If you comment out `data: {title: $(#title").val()` it'll compile just fine.

You may want to also document some of your closing tags when trying to troubleshoot syntax errors.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var url = "http://3920project.azurewebsites.net/api/activity/";
    //var email = "?email=" + getUrlVars();
    //var title = "?title=" + "girls";
    var title = "?title=" + getTitle();

    //alert(url + title);
    $.getJSON(url + title)
    // data: {title: $("#title").val()
    .done(function(res) {
        //alert("done");
        $.each(res, function(key, item) {
            var colID = $('<td>', {
                text: item.category
            });
            var colName = $('<td>', {
                text: item.day + item.to + item.from
            });
            $('<tr>').append(colID, colName).appendTo($('#tblResult:last'));
        }); //end of each()
    }); //end of done()
    }); //end of click()
}); //end of ready()
```

---

**Update**: 
The next step in walking through the code is with `getTitle()`. @blex points out in the comments that you don't have an element that has the ID of Title. So you're getting the console error of `stackoverflow.html:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

**Update**
Now that you've changed the id from `activity` to `title` on your input, things submit correctly, however you have the console error of `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://3920project.azurewebsites.net/api/activity/?title=test. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

This means that you have a CORS problem (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). [Here is an article to help understand that](https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/). Either you aren't setting the correct header flags in making your requests, or the server hasn't whitelisted your domain to make the requests.

Comment: Oh. guess I started posting my answer before he did that. Also, there weren't any answers when I started. I guess I type slower than others, ha.

Comment: @Tess Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @EnigmaRM thank you! another student is in charge of the web service, so I guess that's all I can do to fix it for now.

Comment: @Tess glad I could help. Sounds like a fun project. And very useful: using ajax to request data from an API.

Answer (score 0):

It's your getJSON statement. The object data: {title: $("#title").val() is out of place, missing a closing } and also redundant since you append the title param to the URL.

```
$.getJSON(url + title)
    .done(function(res) {
        //alert("done");
        $.each(res, function(key, item) {
            var colID = $('<td>', {
                text: item.category
            });
            var colName = $('<td>', {
                text: item.day + item.to + item.from
            });
            $('<tr>').append(colID, colName).appendTo($('#tblResult:last'));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect - `data: {title: $("#title").val()`. Try this inside your code:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var url = "http://3920project.azurewebsites.net/api/activity/";
    var title = "?title=" + getTitle();
    $.getJSON(url + title)
    .done(function(res) {
        // Your code here
    })
    .fail(function(err){
        // check error
    });
});
```